# Associate a Native Function calls to Java Method

Tags: java, jvm, native

We are running into native memory leak issues with a Java process.

After linking JVM with jemalloc as recommended in numerous resources like (http://www.evanjones.ca/java-native-leak-bug.html), we were able to boil down the root cause to inflateInit2_ and updatewindow calls in the zlib library.

How do we go about associating these calls from Native space to JVM methods? We already tried looking at the stack trace (hoping to get lucky) and also Flame graphs but these did not help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZipInputStream` / `JarInputStream` is a typical source of such memory leaks, for example, when a `Class.getResourceAsStream` is not closed after use.

Create a heap dump to see who holds `java.util.zip.Inflater` objects.

---

[`async-profiler`](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) recently got support for profiling native memory leaks on Linux. The following command will profile native allocations for `<SEC>` seconds and create a report as a FlameGraph containing combined Java+native stacks:

```
./profiler.sh -e malloc -d <SEC> -o malloc.svg <PID>
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. The heap dump really opened up few ideas to debug further. As a temporary fix, decompressing all the JARs used help control the memory usage.